# Mutual TLS Authentication HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, webapi, pfx

I am trying to request post end point using C#. For this from server side I have certificate and private key using this I want to make mutual TLS authentication and send the certificate to the http client.

Can someone guide me in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any code

Comment: Mutual TLS Authentication means that both the server and the client have their own certificate which they use to authenticate against the other. Having only a server certificate is very common and almost every https site uses it (like Stackoverflow).

The client certificate is much more uncommon. Here you can see how to do it using HttpClient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714614/httpclient-isnt-using-client-certificate-for-mutual-tls-auth